# Remove default date.time appending to artifact name when publishing to maven with gradle

Tags: maven, datetime, gradle, sbt, publish

I'm using gradle with maven-publish plugin to publish artifacts to our local maven repo.

My `build.gradle` looks like (snippet):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'org.myorg'
            artifactId 'myapp'
            version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'myUsername'
                password 'myPassword'
            }
            url 'https://my.repo/snapshots/'
        }
    }
}
```

And after running `publish` output looks like:

```
$ gradle publish
:generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.0.1-20161122.144856-2.jar
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.0.1-20161122.144856-2.jar.sha1
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.0.1-20161122.144856-2.jar.md5
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.0.1-20161122.144856-2.pom
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.0.1-20161122.144856-2.pom.sha1
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.0.1-20161122.144856-2.pom.md5
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.md5
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/maven-metadata.xml
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Upload https://my.repo/snapshots/org/myorg/myapp/maven-metadata.xml.md5
:publish

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.147 secs
```

Files exist and everything "is fine". Not really. Files like `pom` and others have `date.time` appended. Is there a way to not having them appended?

The problems I have is when I'm trying to use `sbt` to add dependency to this new library it fails to fetch it due to this appended date and time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  When you publish a snapshot then maven will in the background rename the file so the latest can always be referenced via `-SNAPSHOT`

If your trying to release your jar then just remove the `-SNAPSHOT` and you will see it upload with the name being `"$project.name-$project.version"` as is.

On the other hand if you would like to reference the jar as a snapshot then you just need to be sure you have added the snapshot repository to your gradle

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    url 'https://my.repo/snapshots/'
}

dependencies {
    compile "some.thing:blah:1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```